# Mixing secure and not secure content in mobile web app

Tags: security, ssl

I have a mobile site served with SSL.
We need to play some audio files which sadly do not play with ssl
If I serve them via http they play just fine
The thing is, if I go that way, am I crippling the security ssl provides?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have the resources, the best way to do it is to have your server receive the request from the user through SSL, and then dynamically create a regular HTTP URL from which the client can be redirected to receive the content.  Serve absolutely nothing else except the audio through this link, and do not exchange any cookies/tokens/keys etc.  Also, if you are using tokens to track session, be sure to set the secure flag on the cookie so that the user's  browser doesn't transmit the contents of the token unless connecting via SSL/HTTPS, otherwise the token will be sent in plaintext over HTTP after being redirected.  The techniques for accomplishing this vary from platform to platform, otherwise I would provide more specific instructions for accomplishing this. However, it is quite common so should be easy to find.

This may also help your performance, because you will save a lot of processing on the server side by avoiding the encryption of SSL.  As long as the audio isn't sensitive, this is the way to go.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A question first. Do you try to play these audio in default browser or do you have an app which plays it? (My guess would be that you are a using browser, since you can't change a client side).

It would be useful if you give a little bit more background on your problem. This way people may come up with all kind of interesting workarounds.

Also, you want to check how browsers will handle it. As example, some browser complains about such things (unsecure content). It could be a turn off for some users.

I think ssl will survive this (you aren't crippling it) :) However, these audio will be in clear and open for all kind of attacks (which ssl prevents from). So, the most critical question is whether you care.

If you play some simple audio effect, you may don't core. If you play some proprietary audio books, it could be very big deal for you.

**Update 1**

One more idea (sorry, I won't be able to provide a fully tested solution, because I am out of my depth here).

Did you consider downloading this audio using a script (through secured channel), storing it in local storage (I believe HTML 5 allows it) or sotring it in memory and plain it from this local storage.

This way you may solve your problem.

Comment: Hi. No app involved. Actually, it is a mobile site and the media are in no way sensitive. Plain background audio.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it's mostly okay as long as it can't inject scripts. An attacker could still replace the video though, perhaps to exploit a hole in the video decoder or for more mundane phishing. It also means you don't protect the confidentiality of videos.